# How to click on a button to start an activity in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to do a simple aplication using Android Studio. First, a log in or sign up activity...

[Log in/Sign up profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HRVV.png)
...That it takes the user to a menu with one button.

[Options menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK8BB.png)
However, when clicking the button it shows the first activity [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HRVV.png) on the screen instead of

[The activity I want to see on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp5n3.png)

I have already written the necessary code in AndroidManifest.xml, but I don´t see where the error is inside the Java code.

[Java code for log in/sign up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTuZr.png)
The Java code for [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HRVV.png) works fine...

[Java code for the menu with the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trlac.png)
...so does the Java code of the second activity, mostly. When I click the button (in the XML file it has the atribute "onClick" and its value it´s the method "nave") it returns to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HRVV.png).

How do I fix this?

Comment: From the screenshots (not a good way to share code btw) it appears you're not calling any methods

Comment: This is not a good way to add links to share screenshots. 

BTW can you share XML code?